# Tangent bundle of complex torus is trivial

Tags: geometry, complex-geometry, tangent-bundle

I've seen [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202613/how-do-i-see-that-the-tangent-bundle-of-torus-is-trivial) and I've been wondering if it's also true in the complex case. So is the holomorphic tangent bundle of the complex torus also trivial? And can one adapt the proof of the real case?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, the coordinates on $\mathbb C^n$ give rise to an explicit trivialization of $\mathbb C^n/\mathbb Z^{2n}$.